# Symlink TO dropbox folder in different user account

Tags: macos, folders, dropbox, symlink

Recently purchased a new Mac to be used as a family Mac. We share my Dropbox account and I have installed this into my user folder.

Question: Can I create a symlink into my wife's documents folder TO the Dropbox folder in my account?

Comment: If your wife used Dropbox, then you could create a set of shared folders and keep documents that way. I find that symlinking other users' folders fraught with inconsistency and sometime data loss. Let Dropbox take care of the synch.

Answer (score 1):

If your wife's account has read/write access to your Dropbox folder, then **a symlink should work**. You might need to give special permission to your Dropbox folder to your wife's account, and apply those permissions to enclosed items…

[image]